# How to get site collections 100 by 100 from sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-server, powershell

I use `Get-SPSite` powershell command to get the site collections in our sharepoint environment. It has only `-Limit 'some value'` or `-Limit All` parameters.

If I have 1000 site collections, can I get 100 by 100 by using `-Filter` parameter or anything ?

Thanks.

Comment: Any specific type of site collections that you would like to retrive? Or just 100 random out of 1000?

Comment: I want to get all 1000 as 100 by 100.

Comment: Any specific reason why you need to do this? I'm thinking it would be easier to export the output of get-spsite -limit all to an Excel file and then group objects by 100 there.

Comment: No, 1000 here is an example. our client has 42300 site collections that it takes more that 45 minutes to get all the result using `-Limit All`.

Answer (score 0):

With the following script you can view all Sites in steps of 100:

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell;

$allSites = Get-SPSite -limit All;

for($i = 1; $i -lt $allSites.Count;$i++)
{
    write-host $allsites[$i-1];

    if($i % 100 -eq 0)
    {
        write-host ($i) "/"  $allSites.Count;
        read-host;
    }
}
```